# How to angle 2 background-images side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have the following design that I need to replicate via css etc. The left/right background images need to be editable via a CMS thus why I have used an inline `background-image` style.

I just want to know how to make the left image have an angled/slanted right edge with a gold border etc and then how to angle the right image so its parallel. Not worried about the content inside them at this stage.

[image]

I have a demo here: http://codepen.io/ifusion/pen/KNxNxL

How would one do this using CSS? I am using bootstrap as well (which has been added in the demo)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `skew` in css.

Here is a sample demo

```
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image_wrap {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative; border-right:4px solid red
}
.image{
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/301/301);
    position:absolute;
    top:-30px;
    left:-30px;
    right:-30px;
    bottom:-30px;
        -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-20deg);

         border-right:4px solid red
}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2mhp38pc/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

you just need to google more about shaping a div.

it just an example and it's highly possible to change like what you wanted

```css
/* reset */
ul, li, a {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
/* nav stuff */
ul, li, a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
/* appearance styling */
ul {
    /* hacks to make one side slant only */
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, white, white, red);
}
li {
    background-color: red;
  transform:skewX(-20deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-20deg);
}
li a {
    padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 80px;
  transform:skewX(20deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(20deg);
    -webkit-transform:skewX(20deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
</ul>
```